# Express SessionID differs from SessionID in Cookie

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis, socket.io

I have a corresponding problem by using the given example.
In the example, the session is used in the WebSocket by reloading it first:

```
  socket.on('set value', function (val) {
    sess.reload(function () {
      sess.value = val;
      sess.touch().save();
    });
  });
```

Trying to use it in my own application, i get the following exception:

```
  sess.reload(function () {
       ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'reload'
```

I think the problem is, that no one defines the variable sess as session:

```
io.listen(app).set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
  if (!data.headers.cookie) 
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);

  data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
  data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];

  store.load(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
    if (err || !session) return accept('Error', false);

    data.session = session;
    return accept(null, true);
  });
})
```

Maybe some has a short fix for this?

**Problem solved:** I tried to use this example: https://github.com/DanielBaulig/sioe-demo/blob/master/app.js with Express 3.0 and Redis.

Therefore i created a Redis Store (connect-redis) instead of a MemoryStore:

```
app.use(express.session({cookie: {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 30*60*60*24*1000)}, secret: SESSION_SECRET, key: SESSION_KEY, store: new RedisStore({host:'localhost', port:'6379', client: dbRedis})}));
```

Since the parseCookie-Method in connect moved i used

```
parseCookie = require('cookie').parse
```

instead of

```
connect.utils.parseCookie
```

To access the session in the cookie i modified the example by using the following:

```
sio.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
  if (!data.headers.cookie) 
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);

  data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
  log.info('Cookie: $s', JSON.stringify(data.cookie));
  data.sessionID = data.cookie['letter.sid'];
  log.info('SessionId: %s', data.sessionID);

  dbRedis.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
    if (err || !session) return accept('Error ' + session, false);

    data.session = session;
    return accept(null, true);
  });
})
```

Now my Problem is, that i cant load the session from Redis because the Session IDs differ
Printing the Session ID on a page (req.sessionID) i get: n+57bnkLr+iXkMLbStWdFzK5
But in Redis the following ID is Stored:

```
[2012-12-03T22:14:56.632Z]  INFO: Postbox/78964 on capns-mba.local: Cookie: $s {"SQLiteManager_currentLangue":"4","connect.sid":"s:xvYdDm5C0MEIg53EG8JgqBnM.Tx8+PMKa570zk6qt9vmCjRz2p/LP/COyyqGSm+VKxww","letter.sid":"s:n+57bnkLr+iXkMLbStWdFzK5.XPHh1xXrK9D4cPfJ7HcHO11PKk8FXLg6fIRGaWb/+jI"}
[2012-12-03T22:14:56.632Z]  INFO: Postbox/78964 on capns-mba.local: SessionId: s:n+57bnkLr+iXkMLbStWdFzK5.XPHh1xXrK9D4cPfJ7HcHO11PKk8FXLg6fIRGaWb/+jI
```

Obviously the req.sessionID is part of the SessionID saved in the cookie/redis - but why? And which is the correct sessionID?

Comment: Ok the problem is that the i don't get a session by using dbRedis.get().

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look at this piece of code from [session middleware](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js) ( line 267 ):

```
var val = 's:' + signature.sign(req.sessionID, secret);
```

where `signature.sign` function is a concatenation ( pseudo-code ):

```
req.sessionID + "." + hash(secret)
```

where `hash` is a custom function ( [see this for more details](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-cookie-signature/blob/master/index.js) ).

This means that it is just a signing convention for cookies ( to make it more secure ). You can retrieve your sid by calling:

```
var signature = require( "cookie-signature" ),
    prefix = "s:";

var real_sid = sid.replace( prefix, "" );
real_sid = signature.unsign( real_sid, SESSION_SECRET );
```

Comment: Few years after you answered this, today, you saved a man's life. Thank you! :)

Comment: In my case I had to do sid = decodeURIComponent(sid); first, because session ID is stored in encoded string in cookie.